# Implementing unread/read checking for a message

Tags: django

I'm having a message model. To this model I want to add a read/unread field, which I did by using a boolean field. Now, if someone reads this message, I want this boolean field to be turned to true. I access these messages at different parts in my app, so updating the field manually is going to be tedious.

Is there any way I can get some messages according to some condition, and when the message is fetched from db, the field gets auto updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create a `read_message()` method on a [custom model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/managers/). Have this method return the messages you want, whilst also updating the field on each message returned.

You new method allow you to replace `Message.objects.get()` with `Message.objects.read_message()`

```
class MessageManager(models.Manager):
    def read_message(self, message_id):
        # This won't fail quietly it'll raise an ObjectDoesNotExist exception
        message = super(MessageManager, self).get(pk=message_id)
        message.read = True
        message.save()
        return message
```

Then include the manager on your model -

```
class Message(models.Model):
    objects = MessageManager()
```

Obviously you could write other methods that return querysets whilst marking all the messages returned as read.

If you don't want to update your code (places where you call `Message.objects.get()`), then you could always actually override `get()` so that it updates the `read` field. Just replace the `read_message` function name above with `get`.

Comment: That's what I did initially, but then I had too many places where I had to repeat this kind of code. I was trying to somehow make this happen in a 'transparent' manner - something like pass the condition and username somewhere, and auto updation occurs. I guess I could write a function for the same, but I was not sure if that was the right approach.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read your question properly. I've updated my answer with a new suggestion

Comment: Nice, I think this is exactly the functionality I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your database management system, you may be able to install a trigger:

PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html

MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

SQLite: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Of course, this will need to be done manually in the database - outside of the Django application.

Comment: Interesting, I've not heard about triggers earlier. I'll check into that.